# Remove XML Nodes using Unix Command Line

Tags: xml, linux, awk, sed, grep

I need to remove nodes from a file if they don't have a certain tag.
How can I only keep nodes which have a name tag using awk, sed or grep?

Input:

```
    <node user="user1">
      <tag k="name" v="name1"/>
    </node>
    <node user="user2">
      <tag k="network" v="nw1"/>
    </node>
```

Desired output:

```
    <node user="user1">
      <tag k="name" v="name1"/>
    </node>
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: No, you absolutely don't do this using "awk, sed oder grep". You do this using xsltproc or xmlstarlet. Please read up on these tools. Also, please ask a question. Currently this is a programming assignment, not a question.

Comment: @Tomalak I need to use awk, grep or grep.

Comment: No, you don't. Give me one valid reason why you need to use command line tool X, while the much more appropriate command line tool Y, which is also installed (!), can't be used.

Comment: @Tomalak it is a requirement from our customer to use one of this tools...

Comment: That's highly unlikely. They want a problem solved, and if they are paying you then I am pretty sure they want it solved properly. If you come to a car repair shop you don't get to tell the mechanic which tools to use, and in the same way your customer is not telling you which tools to use. So... I don't think that you are *really* in that situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Poz '.*<node .*\n.*<tag .*v="name1".*\n.*</node>' file.xml
```

Output:

```
   <node user="user1">
      <tag k="name" v="name1"/>
    </node>
```

Comment: Yes it works, but how can I insert a Newline if I have several output nodes?

Comment: With grep I don't know. I suggest to use Ed Morton's  awk solution and replace `%s%s` by `%s%s\n`. See my comment to his solution. There's a small typo in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

If your file's really that simple, with GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='</node>\n' '/v="name1"/{printf "%s%s", $0, RT}' file
    <node user="user1">
      <tag k="name" v="name1"/>
    </node>
```

Comment: It is not working, the output of your code is: tag k="name" v="name1"/>

Comment: No it's not, see the answer. If whatever you are running is producing that output then you are not running the command in my answer against the input in your question.

Comment: I suggest to replace `RT` by `RS` (typo).

Comment: Thanks, but my ouput is still: tag k="name" v="name1"/>
</node>

Comment: Okay. With my `nawk` I miss `</node>` if I use RT.

Comment: `nawk` is a very old and non-POSIX awk so it doesn't even have the basic functionality of a POSIX awk and anyway RT is a gawk-specific extension as well as multi-char RS - if you say `RS="</node>"` in nawk it will treat it as if you said `RS="<"` and ignore rest of the characters.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints with xmlstarlet and this file (file.xml):

```
<root>
   <node user="user1">
      <tag k="name" v="name1"/>
    </node>
    <node user="user2">
      <tag k="network" v="nw1"/>
    </node>
   <node user="user3">
      <tag k="foo" v="bar"/>
    </node>
</root>
```

Get attributes:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//root/node/tag/@v' file.xml
```

Output:

```
name1
nw1
bar
```

---

Delete one node with attribute `v="name1"`:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//root/node[tag[@v="name1"]]' file.xml
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <node user="user2">
    <tag k="network" v="nw1"/>
  </node>
  <node user="user3">
    <tag k="foo" v="bar"/>
  </node>
</root>
```

---

Delete two nodes with attributes `v="name1"` or `v="bar"`:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//root/node[tag[@v="name1"]]' -d '//root/node[tag[@v="bar"]]' file.xml
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <node user="user2">
    <tag k="network" v="nw1"/>
  </node>
</root>
```